# MongoDB sort by date in column (text)

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to run a query which returns documents between a certain date range.

The date is stored like so: "Mon Feb 19 16:59:40 +0000 2018" in a column called "date". I am aware of sorting by ascending or descending order by running sort {date: -1}, however, I do not believe MongoDB performs this comparison correctly.

I was thinking about converting all these dates via a PHP script to Unix timestamp, however, there must be a way to keep the data as it is and sort by the date column?

My question, therefore, is how would I run a query to retrieve all documents between two dates X and Y? Second question, am I better off pre-processing the date to a Unix timestamp before storing into MongoDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About your first question:
Yes it is possible using aggregate like so:

```
db.coll.aggregate()
  .project({
      dateTimestamp: {
         $dateFromString: {
           dateString: '$date'
        }
     //project additional necessary fields
    }
  })
  .sort({dateTimestamp:1})
```

Second question:
I would probably store it as a date already, if there's no reason not to. Using dates gives you easier query/sorting